# What is a type equation? Could you link me to some sources? Does it have any other names?

Tags: type-theory

I was reading about maybe in [the haskell documentation](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maybe) and it mentioned a type equation. I have been reading a bit on type theory but I had never seen it before. It was not mentioned on the type theory Wikipedia and any attempts to look it up have lead to maths writing software (like LaTeX).

Below is the bit that tripped me up.
[image: image of the equation]

I'm guessing it might have something to do with category theory but I'm not 100% on it.

Also if it is known by some other name that I could look up it would be really helpful to avoid the writing software.

Comment: It looks to me to simply mean an equation between types. But I think that the section you are quoting is not well written at all – it doesn't explain the relevance of $F$ to Maybe, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Haskell's type system definitely has something to do with category theory as referenced here in Haskell wiki [site](https://wiki.haskell.org/Category_theory):

> There exists a "Haskell category", of which the objects are Haskell types, and the morphisms from types a to b are Haskell functions of type a -> b...

So a subset of Haskell called *Hask* is often regarded as a category where $F$ in your above type equation is an [endofunctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functor) mapping the *Hask* category to itself. Maybe type as a [coproduct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coproduct) object in this category is defined and constructed via your above type equation, so the "set" in your doc really means an object in *Hask* category. Usually Maybe type is also called a sum type in functional programming as one of the two common classes of [algebraic data type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_data_type).

Another common type equation is used to characterize a *List* type consisting of elements of type X as: $F(X)=1+XF(X)$, solving this type equation we can get $F(X)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty X^n$. Hope this helps...